# reloadData on CollectionView, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UsersCollectionViewCell


    someRequest(username: self.usernameUrl) { (userInfo, error) in
            guard let userInfo = userInfo else {
                // present error
                return
            }
            print("Running")

            let user_image_url = userInfo.items.map{($0.avatarURL)}
            cell.userCellLabel.text = user_name[indexPath.item]                   
    }     
    return cell
}
```

Why the code inside ***someRequest( ... )*** is not running when I call reloadData on viewDidAppear?

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.collectionViewUsers.reloadData()
}
```

P.s. Somerequest just perform an Alamofire get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async Alamofire request must be outside of the `cellForItemAt` handler. Because `cellForItemAt` is called every time the cell appeared on the screen, that means it will try to fetch same data for same cell for multiple times while scrolling, which is not intended. So `viewDidLoad` is a good place to start fetching, after async call completed don't forget to reload collectionview.

```
var user_image_url: String?
override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    someRequest(username: self.usernameUrl) { (userInfo, error) in
        guard let userInfo = userInfo else {
            // present error
            return
        }
        print("Running")

        user_image_url = userInfo.items.map{($0.avatarURL)}
        self.collectionViewUsers.reloadData()
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UsersCollectionViewCell
    if let user_image_url = user_image_url {
        //user_image_url is avaliable
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, with your answer I understand lot of things ... (mostly about completionHandler). Thank you very much !!